# Update an existing column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column `pass VARCHAR(50)`. I need to change it to `VARCHAR(255)`:

```
ALTER TABLE college 
ALTER column pass varchar (255) NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE college
CHANGE COLUMN pass VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE college
SET COLUMN pass VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL;
```

I tried the above commands, but nothing is working.

Comment: Why not use phpMyAdmin? By going on the table then the column concerned, we can change the number of characters.

Comment: i need to update that on server.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this then ?

```
ALTER TABLE college MODIFY pass VARCHAR(255);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below statement to update your column

```
ALTER TABLE college MODIFY pass varchar(255);
```

Reference: https://www.roseindia.net/sql/sql-alter-column-size.shtml

Answer (score -1):

You are using it wrong, try like that:

```
ALTER TABLE college
 CHANGE  pass pass VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Why you write the column name twice ? And look the official documentation [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-examples.html) . There is no `CHANGE` syntax.

Comment: first is for change pass colum so other will be for modify

Comment: you can also use modify then no need to repeat that colum

Comment: `CHANGE` statement repeat the column name because it is for rename a column. In this case, he want to change the size.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.